# В заданной последовательности неотрицательных чисел найти максимальную сумму двух её элементов. Python

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
max1 = max2 = summa = 0
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    if x > max1 and x != max2:
        max1 = x
    if x > max2 and x != max1:
        max2 = x

if max1+max2 > summa:
    summa = max1+max2
print(summa)
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: решить без использования массива

Comment: И у вас if в конце лишний

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if x > max2 and x != max1:
    max2 = x
```

вы считаете, что в последовательности `3 3 2` два максимальных числа не могут быть одинаковыми?

```
if x > max1:
    max1, max2 = x, max1
elif x > max2:
    max2 = x
```

вот так надо - если `x` больше максимального числа, то максимальное число никуда не девается, оно присваивается второму максимальному числу (меньшему из двух максимальных)

Comment: убрать условие x !=... и в последовательности 8 7 4 будет сумма 16

Comment: Саня, значит это нерешаемая задача, ага

Comment: @Саня, потому что если x больше старшего максимального, то младшее максимальное должно принять значение старшего

Answer (score 1):

```
max1, max2 = 0, 0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    if n > max2:
        max2, max1 = sorted((max1, n))

print(max1 + max2)
```

без `if`

```
max1, max2 = 0, 0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    _, max1, max2= sorted((max1, max2, n))

print(max1 + max2)
```

Comment: Хм, тогда достаточно было бы только второго условия)

Comment: @vp_arth согласен

Comment: Но у вас max2 может обогнать max1 =)

Comment: Предлагаю `max2, max1 = sorted((n, max1))`!

Comment: Дело в том, что первый вариант(с if) некорректен. Сначала не самый большой n попадает в топ, потом самый большой(уже max2) отбрасывается

Comment: @vp_arth сделайте правку и отстаньте от меня

Comment: @vp_arth рәхмәт